# django 1.3 admin problem

Tags: python, django, django-admin

everytime i click on any link in django admin, it will call other urls too, and log me out, so now i can't change anything.

session id is changed everytime too.

i've checked urls.py and the admin ones are at the top of the file.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'developer.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^developer/', include('developer.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Very strange.  Can you give a specific example of which link you click and which other url is called?

Comment: say i go click on a category in it http://localhost:8000/admin/dev/developer/6/

it will log me out. then when i log back in,

it will call the following urls

[08/Jul/2011 15:32:06] "GET /admin/dev/developer/6/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16073
[08/Jul/2011 15:32:06] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2158
[08/Jul/2011 15:32:08] "GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/Jul/2011 15:32:08] "GET /message HTTP/1.1" 200 7413

Comment: What is your `settings.ADMIN_MEDIA` value?

Comment: this is the closest thing to an ADMIN_MEDIA variable i could find. ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'